# flash builder 4.6. how to build air 3.3 sdk in windows

Tags: windows, apache-flex, sdk, air, flash-builder

I have done it step by step in:http://forums.adobe.com/message/3924433 . 
I knew that the flash player now is **11.3**, and the version is **16**.
I also try to change the  and  in air-config.xml, airmobile-config.xml, flex-config.xml.
But when I create a mobile project, it said that "**air33 does not support mobile projects.**"

I can use the air33 sdk by change the flexSDK in .actionScriptProperties, and the project run successfully, but I can not open the Design View, It shows "Design Mode not supported - incompatible SDK version"

Comment: Design View is unfortunately very specific to the Flex SDK.  I guess that changing the version of the AIR Runtime, confuses Flash Builder making it not recongnize the Flex SDK; thus causing Design view to screw up.

Comment: I solved that problem, I just modified the version "3.3" to "4.6.0" in {air SDK}/flex-sdk-description.xml, then I restart the flash builder, So I can open the Design Mode now. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Daniel Albu has some [good instructions](http://www.flashdeveloper.co/post/10985842021/overlay-adobe-air-32-in-flash-builder-46) for overlaying an SDK.

1. [Download the AIR SDK](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/air-sdk-download.html)
2. Locate your current SDKs from your Flash Builder directory

   ```
   Windows 32-bit: C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\sdks 
   Windows 64-bit: C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\sdks)
   ```
3. Make a copy of the current SDK folder (4.6.0 folder) and change the name of the new folder to 4.6.0_AIR3.3
4. Overwrite the new SDK folder (4.6.0_AIR3.3) with the newly loaded AIR 3.3 SDK.  You should approve all overwrite notifications you get from the operating system during this process.
5. Rename the new SDK - Go to the new SDK directory (4.6.0_AIR3.3) and edit flex-sdk-description.xml.  Change the value inside the  tags to Flex 4.6.0 (AIR 3.3).
6. Add the new ‘Playerglobal.swc’ file to add support for Flash Player 11.  [Download the Flash Player 11.3 API file “playerglobal.swc”](http://download.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/updaters/11/playerglobal11_3.swc) and put it into the new SDK folder.  In your new SDK folder go to /frameworks/libs/player/ and create a folder with the name 11.3 and place the “playerglobal11_3.swc” file in it.
7. Add the AIR 3.3 SDK to Flash Builder.  Go to Project -> Properties -> Flex Compiler;  Choose “Configure Flex SDKs”;  Click Add and choose the our new folder;  In the “Additional compiler arguments” text field add “-swf-version=15”
8. Configure your AIR projects.  Set the namespace in your X-app.xml to 3.3 by adding this tag:

   ```
   <application xmlns=”http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.3“>
   ```
9. For web based Stage3D, update the html-template `index.template.html` adding `params.wmode = "direct";` around line 48.

Comment: thank you, I have solved this problem. see the comment that I replied to upstairs.  ↑

Answer (score 0):

Regarding cheating Flash Builder about the Flex SDK you are using, I think I've posted a better solution as an answer to this other post in Stack Overflow:
[can i use design mode in fb 4.6 if I add apache flex sdk 4.9.1 as my compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52594125/10438024)

The trick is done by patching a byte in a class of Flash Builder 4.6, and after doing so, you can use the Flash Builder's visual designer with any version of Flex SDK you want.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't post link-only answers to other Stack Overflow questions. Instead, vote/flag to close as duplicate, or, if the question is not a duplicate, *tailor the answer to this specific question.*