# 4.7 Flash Builder Not Supporting Design View

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

I am using Flash Builder 4.7 But not getting view in MXML Editor How to get it?

How can I get view mode in MXML editor in flash 4.7, assuming 4.7 has this feature?

Comment: In flash 4.6 In mxml editor you can find source and view mode while designing the pages but in 4.7 only source is there in mxml editor?

Answer (score 2):

Design View was removed in FB 4.7:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/whitepapers/roadmap.html:

> In order to better support future Apache-derived Flex SDKs, Design
>   View, Data Centric Development tools, and Flash Catalyst workflows
>   will be removed in updated 4.x versions of Flash Builder.

Answer (score 0):

[Design View Removed](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1056583)

you can try:

[can i use design mode in fb 4.6 if I add apache flex sdk 4.9.1 as my compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15665980/can-i-use-design-mode-in-fb-4-6-if-i-add-apache-flex-sdk-4-9-1-as-my-compiler)